# How to Deploy & access swagger-ui on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, heroku, swagger, swagger-ui

I successfully run swagger-ui and swagger-editor locally by using their dockerize image and this is my `docker-compose.yml`.

```
      swagger-editor:
        image: swaggerapi/swagger-editor
        container_name: "swagger-editor"
        ports:
          - "8081:8080"
        networks:
          - eb-back_network
    
      swagger-ui:
        image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
        container_name: "swagger-ui"
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "8082:8080"
        volumes:
          - ./swagger/swagger.json:/swagger.json
        environment:
          SWAGGER_JSON: /swagger.json
        networks:
          - eb-back_network
```

I can access swagger-editor on `localhost:8081` & swagger-ui on localhost:8082.
I deployed my app o Heroku by following [Container Registry & Runtime (Docker Deploys)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)
It works fine but I can't access swagger on Heroku.

I don't know how to do this?
I think images which I run locally have nothing to do with Heroku or I have to use some addons but I don't know the URL from which I can access swagger on heroku ?.

Answer (score 0):

A WebDyno exposes only one port so you cannot serve 2 apps on the same Dyno.

You can merge the 2 apps where each one has a different url (`/swagger-editor` and `swagger-ui`).

Or you can create 2 Heroku apps (one of each) so you get 2 different urls (`swagger-editor.herokuapp.com` and `swagger-ui.herokuapp.com`).
If you use the Heroku Docker Registry this should be straight-forward: build 2 images with the same code but each Dockerfile starts a different app.